# idiom/phrase to say that you do not have to feel unworthy compared to someone else

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an idiom/phrase to illustrate that 'you do not have to feel less worthy/less equipped than someone else'?
In my mother tongue we say "You don't have to stand back a single step from that person", but I don't think that translates to English correctly?

Comment: Sounds like the ugly duckling syndrome.

Comment: I think more clarity is needed. Is the other person superior in some way, but you're being told that it doesn't matter? (Possibly in this case the way in which they're superior isn't relevant to the current situation.) Or does the phrase mean that the person isn't actually superior to you at all, that you're just as good as them?

Answer (score 1):

> **[second to none](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/second+to+none)**
>
> ***better than anything or anyone else***
>
> *The hotel's restaurant is second to none.*

"You don't have to stand back a single step from that person", - ***you are second to none.***

Comment: Thanks., 'second to none' is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Then, accept it against somebody's down voting!

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted this. *second to none* means *the best* or *incomparable*. I don't think this comes close to what OP has described in his question. OP is looking for a phrase that means *you're not less than someone/anyone* not *you're the best*. Why OP thinks this answers his query is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

A similar feeling can be expressed as:

> **He puts his pants on one leg at a time.**
>   *Prov.* The person referred to is only human.; The person referred to is an ordinary person. *Sue: That man is my favorite movie star.
>   Don'tyou think he's just divine? Jane: Oh, I don't know. I imagine he
>   puts his pants on one leg at a time.*

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/He+puts+his+pants+on+one+leg+at+a+time)